# jquery deselecting radio button bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Jquery is deselecting my radio button which is in a dialog when another dialog is also opened. Running through in debug, the culprit in the jquery source is this line:

```
if ( !eventHandle ) {
  elemData.handle = eventHandle = function() {
    // Handle the second event of a trigger and when
    // an event is called after a page has unloaded
    return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && !jQuery.event.triggered ?
    jQuery.event.handle.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
    undefined;//after this line executes selected radio button is lost.
  };
}
```

does anyone know why this is?

simplified version of what is causing this:

```
$("#editYes").click(function(){//this radio is inside a dialog
  if($("#editsList").children().size()==0){
    $('#editDialogDiv').dialog('open');
    setDateHints();
    $('#editOpen').val("true");
  }
  //jquery code above runs here. Upto this point the radio remains selected
});
```

html is something like this:

```
<div title="atitle" id="dialog1">
...
 Yes<input id="editYes" type="radio" value="true" name="edits"> <!-- click this to open second dialog, but its then deselected by jquery-->
 No<input id="editNo" type="radio" value="false" name="edits">
...
</div>
<div title="anothertitle" id="secondDialog">
...some content
</div>
```

Comment: You're looking for a bug in your page in the jQuery source? I doubt that's the correct place to search :)

Comment: Can you post an example of your code which behaves this way please?

Comment: Does both of your dialogs' radio buttons share the same name?

Comment: jQuery is not the culprit, your code should be buggy.

Comment: Hi all I have added my code. As you can see its not my code which is doing it, but I guess it could be because of the design of my code?

Comment: Code alone won't really help in your case, some of the corresponding markup or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the issue would be nice. Also check if your radios in both dialogs don't share the same name.

Comment: There's only one radio in the first dialog. The markup is complex. Jsfiddle wont be able to handle jqueryui?

Comment: You can include jQuery UI by adding a source on left panel of jsfiddle.

Comment: have you tried change events instead of click events?

Comment: @ericosg that worked, thanks. Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event and not the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) since your issue is the order in which the actions take place.

Using the click does not register the change until your event ends. However, your event carries to a new window and loses the returning change action. 
Using change will register the change to your input, then process your actions.